# how to call 2 different arrays for two different pickerviews (swift4)

Tags: ios, tags, uitextfield, swift4, uipickerview

My code below features two different textfields ana and sampleTextfield. Right now sampleTextfield works perfectly calling arrray firstHit. But I am trying to figure out how to have ana call and display array secondHit. Right now sampleTextfield is tagged at 1 and ana is tagged at 2. I think tagging is the best way to do this.

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {


    let myBUtton = UIButton()

    @IBOutlet var ana : UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var sampleTextField: UITextField!

    var initialc:[NSLayoutConstraint] = []
    var buttonCons:[NSLayoutConstraint] = []
    var textCons:[NSLayoutConstraint] = []
    var textCons2:[NSLayoutConstraint] = []
    var textAna:[NSLayoutConstraint] = []

    var selecteDay : String?



    let firstHit = ["","X","9","8","7","6","5","4","3","2","1","0"]
    let secondHit = ["\\","9","8","7","6","5","4","3","2","1","0"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        createToolBar()
        createDayPicker()
        sampleTextField.placeholder = "Enter text here"
        sampleTextField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        sampleTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sampleTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.roundedRect
        sampleTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
        sampleTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
        sampleTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
        sampleTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.whileEditing;
        sampleTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.center

        self.view.addSubview(sampleTextField)

        ana.placeholder = "Enter text here"
        ana.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        ana.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        ana.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.roundedRect
        ana.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
        ana.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
        ana.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
        ana.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.whileEditing;
        ana.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.center

        self.view.addSubview(ana)
        sampleTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let leadingc2 = sampleTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80)
        let trailingC2 = sampleTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
        let topc2 = sampleTextField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor, constant: -70)
        let bottomc2 = sampleTextField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor, constant: -250)

        textCons = [leadingc2,trailingC2,topc2,bottomc2]




        let leadingc2a = ana.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80)
        let trailingC2a = ana.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
        let topc2a = ana.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor, constant: 70)
        let bottomc2a = ana.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor, constant: -250)

        textAna = [leadingc2a,trailingC2a,topc2a,bottomc2a]

        ana.backgroundColor = .gray
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(textCons)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(textAna)


    }
    func createDayPicker () {
        let dayPicker = UIPickerView()
        dayPicker.tag = 0 
        dayPicker.delegate = self
        dayPicker.backgroundColor = .black
        sampleTextField.inputView = dayPicker

    }


    func createToolBar()  {
        let toolbar = UIToolbar()
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
        let doneButonnt = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.cancle))
        toolbar.setItems([doneButonnt], animated: false)
        toolbar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        sampleTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    }

    @objc func cancle() {
        view.endEditing(true)


        if sampleTextField.text == "X"{

            ana.isHidden = true
            sampleTextField.backgroundColor = .red
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(textCons)
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(textAna)



            sampleTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            let leadingc2 = sampleTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80)
            let trailingC2 = sampleTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
            let topc2 = sampleTextField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor, constant: -70)
            let bottomc2 = sampleTextField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor, constant: -250)
                   let rightCona = sampleTextField.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor)
                   let leftCona = sampleTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor)
            textCons2 = [leadingc2,trailingC2,topc2,bottomc2,rightCona,leftCona]
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(textCons2)



        }

        else {
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(textCons2)
            ana.isHidden = false

            sampleTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            let leadingc2 = sampleTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80)
            let trailingC2 = sampleTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
            let topc2 = sampleTextField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor, constant: -70)
            let bottomc2 = sampleTextField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor, constant: -250)

            textCons = [leadingc2,trailingC2,topc2,bottomc2]




            let leadingc2a = ana.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80)
            let trailingC2a = ana.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
            let topc2a = ana.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor, constant: 70)
            let bottomc2a = ana.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor, constant: -250)

            textAna = [leadingc2a,trailingC2a,topc2a,bottomc2a]

            ana.backgroundColor = .gray
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(textCons)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(textAna)
        }

    }
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {


        return 1

    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        return firstHit.count
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return firstHit[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {


            selecteDay = firstHit[row]
            sampleTextField.text = selecteDay

    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        var lable: UILabel
        if let view = view as? UILabel {
            lable = view
        } else {
            lable = UILabel()
        }

        lable.textColor = .white
        lable.textAlignment = .center
        lable.font = UIFont(name: "Menlo-Regular", size: 17)
        lable.text = firstHit[row]
        return lable
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach that I can think of is as follow:

```
    import UIKit

//Indicator to indicate which field is currently active at the moment
enum ActiveField {
  case ana
  case sample
}

//protocol that different source will be using or conforms to
protocol PickerData {
    var source: [String] { get }
    var active: ActiveField { get }
}


//The first source
struct FirstHit: PickerData {
    var source: [String]
    var active: ActiveField
}

//The second source
struct SecondHit: PickerData {
    var source: [String]
    var active: ActiveField
}



class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


let myBUtton = UIButton()

@IBOutlet var ana : UITextField!
@IBOutlet var sampleTextField: UITextField!

//These are the actual data received or manually set as the case here
let firstHit = FirstHit(source: ["","X","9","8","7","6","5","4","3","2","1","0"], active: .ana)
let secondHit = SecondHit(source: ["\\","9","8","7","6","5","4","3","2","1","0"], active: .sample)

//This one will be used to determine the title displayed in picker view
var pickerDataSource: PickerData!

//We will use this pickerview for all inputs view
var dayPicker: UIPickerView!


// MARK: - LifeCycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //1. create the pickerView
    createDayPicker()

    //2. create the toolbar
    createToolBar()

    //3. set the pickerview as input to textFields (same pickerview)
    ana.inputView = dayPicker
    sampleTextField.inputView = dayPicker

    //4. set the textField delegate so that when they become active we know what source to use
    ana.delegate = self
    sampleTextField.delegate = self
}


func createDayPicker () {
    dayPicker = UIPickerView()
    dayPicker.delegate = self
    dayPicker.dataSource = self
    dayPicker.backgroundColor = .black
}


func createToolBar()  {
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    let doneButonnt = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.cancle))
    toolbar.setItems([doneButonnt], animated: false)
    toolbar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    sampleTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    ana.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
}

@objc func cancle() {
    view.endEditing(true)

    //...Do stuff
}


// MARK: - TextField Delegate
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    //set the appropriate source
    if textField == ana {
        pickerDataSource = firstHit
    } else if textField == sampleTextField {
        pickerDataSource = secondHit
    }

    //reload picker
    dayPicker.reloadAllComponents()

    return true
    }
}
```

Just separating pickerView delegate and dataSource to extension

```
extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1 //since we only have one component to display
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerDataSource.source.count //the count of element inside source
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickerDataSource.source[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    //to know which field is active so that we can identify and set value to that field we are using ActivePicker
    switch pickerDataSource.active {
    case .ana:
        ana.text = pickerDataSource.source[row]
    case .sample:
        sampleTextField.text = pickerDataSource.source[row]
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    var lable: UILabel
    if let view = view as? UILabel {
        lable = view
    } else {
        lable = UILabel()
    }

    lable.textColor = .white
    lable.textAlignment = .center
    lable.font = UIFont(name: "Menlo-Regular", size: 17)
    lable.text = pickerDataSource.source[row]
    return lable
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you assign the inputView , give the pickerView a tag

```
let dayPicker = UIPickerView()
dayPicker.tag = 0 // it's default also , and set 1 for the other picker
```

//

Use the tag to differentiate

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
   return ( pickerView.tag == 0 ) ? firstHit.count : secondHit.count
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return ( pickerView.tag == 0 ) ? firstHit[row] : secondHit[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if pickerView.tag == 0 {
        selecteDay = firstHit[row]
        sampleTextField.text = selecteDay
    }
    else {
        selecteSec = secondHit[row]
        anaTextField.text = selecteSec 
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you be a little more specific

Comment: This line return ( pickerView.tag == 0 ) ? firstHit.count : secondHit.count.

Comment: it's equivalent to **if  pickerView.tag == 0 { return firstHit.count  } else { return  secondHit.count }** ,  search for Ternary operator

Comment: Two questions where do I put let dayPicker = UIPickerView()
dayPicker.tag = 0, in func createDayPicker(). Also I am confused on  selecteSec = secondHit[row] because it has never been declared.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource,UITextFieldDelegate {

let firstHit = ["a","b"]
let secondHit = ["c","d","p"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ...

    sampleTextField.placeholder = "Enter text here"
    sampleTextField.delegate = self

    ...

    ana.placeholder = "Enter text here"
    ana.delegate = self

    ...
}


let dayPicker = UIPickerView()

func createDayPicker () {
    dayPicker.delegate = self
    dayPicker.backgroundColor = .black
    sampleTextField.inputView = dayPicker
    ana.inputView = dayPicker
}

 @objc func cancle() {
    view.endEditing(true)
    ...
}

func createToolBar()  {

    ...

    sampleTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    ana.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
}

var activeTextField = UITextField()
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    activeTextField = textField
    dayPicker.reloadAllComponents()

}

var getArray: [String] {
    if activeTextField == sampleTextField {
        return firstHit
    } else {
        return secondHit
    }
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

   return getArray.count
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return getArray[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if activeTextField == sampleTextField {
        sampleTextField.text = getArray[row]
        //
    }
    else {
        //
        ana.text = getArray[row]
    }

}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let lable = UILabel()
    lable.text = getArray[row]
    return lable
}

}
```

Comment: I updated my question above.  This code does not work.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I dont know what to put in the gaps of your code. For example   if activeTextField == sampleTextField {
        //
    }
    else {
        //
    }

Comment: I think its getting better but   sampleTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar is not working due to a toolbar not being declared. And I need to know what to put into    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        <#code#>
    }.

Comment: I share my code https://github.com/leninsmannath/PickerViewTest/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks better to create 2 separate Pickers.

Architecture-wise I thing is better to do the following:

1. Create separate Delegate and DataSource objects for picker;
2. Initialize it with a proper array;

Something like this:

```
class SomeController: UIViewController {

    lazy var picker1: UIPickerView = {
       return UIPickerView()
    }()


    lazy var picker2: UIPickerView = {
        return UIPickerView()
    }()

    let arr1: [String] = []
    let arr2: [String] = []

    var p1delegate: PickerDelegate?
    var p1dataSourse: PickerDataSource?

    var p2delegate: PickerDelegate?
    var p2dataSourse: PickerDataSource?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        configurePicker1()
        configurePicker2()
    }

    func configurePicker1() {
        p1delegate = PickerDelegate(array: arr1)
        p1dataSourse = PickerDataSource(array: arr1)
        picker1.delegate = p1delegate
        picker1.dataSource = p1dataSourse
    }

    func configurePicker2() {
        p2delegate = PickerDelegate(array: arr2)
        p2dataSourse = PickerDataSource(array: arr2)
        picker2.delegate = p2delegate
        picker2.dataSource = p2dataSourse
    }
}


class PickerDataSource: NSObject {
    let array: [String]

    init(array: [String]) {
        self.array = array
    }
}

extension PickerDataSource: UIPickerViewDataSource {
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    // ...
}

class PickerDelegate: NSObject {
    let array: [String]

    init(array: [String]) {
        self.array = array
    }
}

extension PickerDelegate: UIPickerViewDelegate {

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return array[row]
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give the tag to your both picker view then Declare 2 variables:-

```
 let dayPicker = UIPickerView()
    dayPicker.tag = 0 
    let otherPicker = UIPickerView()
    otherPicker.tag = 1
    var firstHitPickerSelectedValue = ""
    var secondHitPickerSelectedValue = ""
    //then write pickerView delegate/dataSourcemethod as below:-

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
   return ( pickerView.tag == 0 ) ? firstHit.count : secondHit.count
// same as if (pickerView.tag == 0) {return firstHit.count} else {return secondHit.count}
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return ( pickerView.tag == 0 ) ? firstHit[row] : secondHit[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if pickerView.tag == 0 {
        firstHitPickerSelectedValue = firstHit[row]
        sampleTextField.text = firstHitPickerSelectedValue
    }
    else {
        secondHitPickerSelectedValue = secondHit[row]
        anyTextField.text = secondHitPickerSelectedValue 
    }
}
```